# ListView SelectedItem not firing in MVVM app using Template 10 UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, mvvm, uwp

I have this XAML...

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AllRoundIDs}" Height="96"
          SelectedItem="{Binding AllRoundsSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Padding="0,0,0,1" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And this code in my ViewModel...

```
    private ObservableCollection<KeyValuePairs> _AllRoundIDs;
    public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePairs> AllRoundIDs
    {
        get { return _AllRoundIDs; }
        private set { Set(ref _AllRoundIDs, value); }
    }
    private KeyValuePairs _AllRoundsSelectedItem;
    public KeyValuePairs AllRoundsSelectedItem
    {
        get { return _AllRoundsSelectedItem; }
        private set { Set(ref _AllRoundsSelectedItem, value); }
    }
```

The KeyValuePairs Class looks like this...

```
public class KeyValuePairs
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

When I run my app I get items in my ListView as expected. So I know the data binding is working.

What I do not get is any life when I click an item. The binding to the AllRoundsSelectedItem does not fire. This code works fine in a WPF app but I get nothing in UWP. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `AllRoundsSelectedItem` property's setter is private, so the `ListView` can't access it. You'll probably find there's a binding error in your output to that effect.

As an aside, because the `KeyValuePairs` class represents a single pair, it should probably be named `KeyValuePair`.

Comment: OMG I can't believe I didn't see that. Fresh eyes from you. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I did use the build in KeyValuePair but was getting nowhere so thought I'd try my own class. Thank you so much.